# Email setting using sendgrid api key in ROR production environment generate diffrent link in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sendgrid

i have setup email setting in ROR application to this path config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV['DOMAIN'], port: ENV['PORT'] }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp 



 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    domain: ENV['DOMAIN'],
    address:        "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    port:            587,
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name:      'apikey',
    password:       ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']
}
```

however email is generated with this settings while forget password link pressed, i checked with log/production.rb  my forget password link like this https://portalone.io/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=pzdE6STwsome_token_value,

but when actual email coming link is like this "http://engage.portalone.io/ls/click?upn=zQLI1Vr0Ey8muJ-2BOnIhkrUQyvtQqre0kl7NH34nsjiGYm7ltsu8gvQ4-2BQCwy9KYn4fVBjnUZJhK7dwFkplSlYHpgPYpqFXVIDKftUZLdvNnGtkbZ-2BHINuPJhfCIZaFTUnVnP_AXyz7OatZUcmRHCwTsMzBA309EZZwKzNu1SV20famO77yr11YyTNieR1NRhMdq7JKEJfFXN1mGyv6miLU4YnM5F6CyeDA7tZG-2BqnTzWpKLQUPSEs6H4nRMaqj5Gl5HznqSIj7EavHgT23kQQslUo-2FPOuQnzsShbVoOeUJ5BUE0jNkUNnPIGwJj4zjJjb2XIZIjkSMliL3ctpNGT-2Ffo2XmafjoFtaMB4uLEPjhwc5nyg-3D"

is there any settings i missed here with sendgrid api key?

Answer (score 1):

Could you check on Sendgrid if you enable the click tracking feature? It will override your links in emails.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/tracking